# Connecting Spring Cloud Config and AWS Code Commit using HTTPS credentials

Tags: spring-cloud-config, aws-codecommit

I am trying to connect my Spring Cloud Config to a repo on AWS CodeCommit using HTTPS but I keep getting an error saying Cannot clone or checkout repository.

This is what I have done so far:

1. Created a user in AWS IAM and generated HTTPS GIT username and password credentials.
2. Added the AWS CodeCommit git URL and user credentials into the application.yml file

   ```
   server:   
      port: 8888
   spring:   
    cloud:
      config:
        discovery:
          enabled: true
        server:
          encrypt.enabled: false
          git:
            uri: https://git-codecommit.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/XXXXX
          username: XXXXXXXXXX
          password: XXXXXXXXXX
   ```
3. Added the AWS java-sdk-core library as a build dependency.

Is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Document encrypt.* values need to go in bootstrap.{yml|properites}